# Cannot access this.state from React function even after using this.bind()

Tags: reactjs, email, this

There are tons of questions on this topic and they all seem to point to an answer that I already knew about, binding functions in the constructor using this.bind.

From handleChange() I am able to update this.state.feedback because I can see each letter I type updated in the form but right after that i try to console.log(this.state.feedback) and it's undefined. I'm also not able to access this.state from handleSubmit() or sendFeedback() as it is also undefined there as well.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I just want to access this.state.feedback from handleSubmit(). Everything works except that. The email is being sent but it's empty since feedback is undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EmailForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formSubmitted: false,
            feedback: ""
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.sendFeedback = this.sendFeedback.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const {
            REACT_APP_EMAILJS_RECEIVER: receiverEmail,
            REACT_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATEID: template
        } = process.env;

        //let feedback  = this.state.feedback;
        //console.log(`feedback: ${this.state.feedback}`);
        this.sendFeedback(
            template,
            this.props.senderEmail,
            receiverEmail,
            this.state.feedback);


        this.setState({
            formSubmitted: true
        })
    }

    handleClose() {
        console.log("Closing");  // TODO fix this
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            feedback: event.target.value.feedback
        });
        console.log(this.state.feedback);
    }

    sendFeedback (templateId, senderEmail, receiverEmail, feedback) {
        console.log(`feedback: ${feedback}`);
        console.log(`this.state.feedback ${this.state.feedback}`);
        window.emailjs.send(
            'default_service',
            templateId,
            {
                senderEmail,
                receiverEmail,
                feedback
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ formEmailSent: true });
                console.log("Email sent!");
            })
            // Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
            .catch(err => console.error('Failed to send feedback. Error: ', err))
    }

    render() {
        //let feedback = "";
        return(
            <form className="feedback-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Your Feedback</h1>
                <textarea
                    className="text-input"
                    id="feedback-entry"
                    name="feedback-entry"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    placeholder="Enter your feedback here"
                    required
                    value={this.state.feedback}
                />
                <div className="btn-group">
                    <button className="btn btn--cancel" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn--submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default EmailForm;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at your `handleChange` function

To get the value of the event you just do:

```
event.target.value
```

You are instead trying to access `event.target.value.feedback`, which will always be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely common React question here.

`setState` is asynchronous. An asynchronous function will be executed in parallel (well, kind of) as other instruction. Your `console.log` will be called before the function is done.

If you want to see the result of it, you will have to use the callback function that will be called when its done as its second argument :

```
this.setState({
    feedback: event.target.value.feedback
}, () => { console.log(this.state.feedback) });
```

And also, the answer just above.
You will need to apply both fixes.

Comment: You are right and it’s a valid statement. But Ryan’s problem was because he was updating the state with an undefined value

Comment: After fixing the problem you mentioned, he will notice the problem I mentioned. That's the point